# Finding the correlation matrix in java

Tags: java

I have to find the correlation of a matrix.I have the csv file,And i stored it into the database. From the database i stored them into a xt matrix .xt contains 11 variables(columns),10000(rows).Now i called the function computeCorrelationMatrix(xt) but it is giving the error

> (Type mismatch: cannot convert from RealMatrix to RealMatrix[][])

```
RealMatrix corr[][] = new RealMatrix [tNumber+1][tNumber+1];// defining corr[][] matrix.

corr  =pc.computeCorrelationMatrix(xt); (Found this function in API)
```

Can any body guide me weather it is the right way of doing or not? If not can you please suggest me how to find?

Comment: What API are you using?  `RealMatrix` is not a standard Java SE or EE API.

Comment: Java Code Examples for org.apache.commons.math.linear.RealMatrix

Comment: public RealMatrix computeCorrelationMatrix(RealMatrix matrix){
  int nVars=matrix.getColumnDimension();
  RealMatrix outMatrix=new BlockRealMatrix(nVars,nVars);
  for (int i=0; i < nVars; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
      double corr=correlation(matrix.getColumn(i),matrix.getColumn(j));
      outMatrix.setEntry(i,j,corr);
      outMatrix.setEntry(j,i,corr);
    }
    outMatrix.setEntry(i,i,1d);
  }
  return outMatrix;
} This is the function mentioned in the api

Comment: can you please help me on that one

Comment: How to use this for autocorrelation (correlation with itself)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the error message is (in effect) telling you that

```
RealMatrix corr[][] = new RealMatrix [tNumber+1][tNumber+1];
```

should be

```
RealMatrix corr;
```

What your code currently says is to create 2D array whose elements are `RealMatrix`.  And it seems that `computeCorrelationMatrix` returns a single `RealMatrix` instance ... not a 2D array of them.

I should also point out that initializing the 2D array and then assigning to it is pointless.  The following assignment is going to overwrite the reference, and the value you created in the initialization will be thrown away.

Notice you the `computeCorrelationMatrix` is creating a matrix object and returning it.  You don't need to create one yourself ... let alone a 2D array of matrices!